# How to add go button and will open google map via my phone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

```
function initializeMap() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("allmap")); 
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $s['latitude']; ?>,<?php echo $s['longitude']; ?>), 16); 
        var latlng = new GLatLng(<?php echo $s['latitude']; ?>,<?php echo $s['longitude']; ?>); 
        map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng)); 
        map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(),document.createTextNode("<?php echo $s['name']; ?>"));
    }
}
```

I wan to add get me direction on footer

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want..

Comment: I'm guessing that you want a button that open google maps in a new tab on a browser with centered in actual `map.getCenter()` value?. Please realize that we want to help you! But we need to know what exactly do you want!

Comment: The posted code is from the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2).  That has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010 and should not be used for new code, use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: @frikinside precisely u got my means. My website is focus on mobile, and plan to add one button on map. Same as Wechat app send location when u click GO then open in google map app automatic get direction from your currently location to the location you received. Between that I got receive location,and I want to add GO function now.

Comment: @geocodezip the code currently used for test only. Will update after. Thank for advise.

Comment: @Robbin'Roboroads'Schepers look on comment me with frikinside. He get the means I wan,

Comment: @Philip He said "I'm guessing that" which indicates he was also unclear about what you meant. Please include more detailed information next time :).

Comment: @Robbin 'Roboroads' Schepers bro,sorry for my word. Okays thank for your advise. Will improve my information detailed next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a link and treat like a button, or use a button with an onclick function that open a new tab.

That's easy but may be you wonder wich url you should use.
You can use this url template: `https://www.google.com/maps/@{lat},{long},{zoom}z`
And get the values of `lattitude` and `longitude` from the map center.

Let's see an example:

### HTML:

```
<div id="allmap"></div>
<button id="gobutton">GO</button>
```

### Javascript:

```
function initializeMap() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("allmap")); 
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $s['latitude']; ?>,<?php echo $s['longitude']; ?>), 16); 
        var latlng = new GLatLng(<?php echo $s['latitude']; ?>,<?php echo $s['longitude']; ?>); 
        map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng)); 
        map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(),document.createTextNode("<?php echo $s['name']; ?>"));

        var button = document.getElementById("gobutton");
        button.onclick = function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/@' + center.lat() + ',' + center.lng() + ',16z');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your comment. it give me some idea to done it. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad to be helpful! If this helps you and answer your question, please mark it as an answer.